# Flutter Run Error - Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to build my Flutter mobile app in Andiord and I'm getting the following error when I run flutter run

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback;)V
```

I tried flutter clean, I have the latest version of flutter and I'm on the stable channel. I also did pup upgrade and migrated to AnndriodX, flutter doctors comes back all ok, nothing seems to work.

I have

- compileSdkVersion 28
- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 28

And throw new `GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")`

Comment: have you set flutter sdk path and install flutter and dart plugin in android studio?

Comment: Yes, I updated Andiord Studio which seems to fix this issue getting something else now but looks like it's moving forward

Answer (score 0):

I updated Andirod Studio which seems to fix this issue